# SQL SORT BY ALTERNATE YEAR

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

Existing Data:

```
RowId   Title   Year
1        Aaa    2002
2        Bbb    2003
3        Ccc    2004
4        Ddd    2004
5        Eee    2005
6        Fff    2006
7        Ggg    2007
8        Hhh    2008
```

I have a need to retrieve the data from the above table based on the input parameter, year as follows:

```
    1.  Select all records matching param year
    2.  Select all records matching param year +1
    3.  Select all records matching param year -1
    4.  Select all records matching param year +2
    5.  Select all records matching param year -2
    6.  Select all records matching param year +3
    7.  Select all records matching param year -3
```

Expected Results (assuming param year is 2005):

```
RowId   Title   Year
5        Eee    2005
6        Fff    2006
3        Ccc    2004
4        Ddd    2004
7        Ggg    2007
2        Bbb    2003
8        Hhh    2008
1        Aaa    2002
```

I was able to achieve it using multiple SELECT on same table with UNION but wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `Year` is an integer:

```
declare @param int

select *
from mytable
where Year = @param
or Year = @param + 1
or Year = @param - 1
-- etc.
order by abs(Year - @param), Year - @param desc, Title
```

The first clause in the `order by` sorts by the magnitude of the difference between `Year` and `@param`, and the second makes sure positive differences come before negative ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE Year = @Year Or 
      Year = @Year - 1 Or 
      Year = @Year + 1 Or
      Year = @Year - 2 Or 
      Year = @Year + 2 Or
      Year = @Year - 3 Or 
      Year = @Year + 3 
ORDER BY ABS(Year - @Year)
```

Comment: That where clause is really verbose: `where Year between (@year - 3) and (@year + 3)` should do. Also, the order by clause isn't quite sufficient. Consider the case when @year = 2006. `ABS(@year - 2005)` and `ABS(@year - 2007)` both yield 1, so they are treated as equal by the order by clause and thus could be returned in any order. If you throw in a second ordering criterion of year, that should do it.

Comment: @BenThul, yep, you are correct. This was posted throught pad, so I could not test it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
select [Row], [Title], [Year], abs(year-2005) as thing
from table1
order by thing, year desc
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e5e4/2

Answer (score 0):

you would need to change 2005 for a param but this should work

```
select rowid, title, year FROM
(
select rowid, title, year, (year - 2005) c1, ABS (year - 2005) c2  from a
  ) t1 
  order by t1.c2, t1.c1 desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b42d0/4